# How to create dynamic headers on a text file using BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have 5 big text files in a directory with millions of records delimited by pipe.  All I want to do is, when I run the BASH script it should create a header on the first line like this:

```
TCR1|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records
```

and the first word(`TCR`) is the new name of the file and last one is the number of records. Both of them should change with respect to each text file. So, when I run the script once, it should find the 5 text files in the directory and script as mentioned above. The output should look like this in each text file.

`a.txt`

```
TCR1|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records in first text file
```

`b.txt`

```
TCR2|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records in second text file
```

`c.txt`

```
TCR3|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records in third text file
```

`d.txt`

```
TCR4|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records in fourth text file
```

`e.txt`

```
TCR5|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records in fifth text file
```

Comment: Your records are delimited by pipe symbols? Or records are delimited by linefeeds and the fields in each record by pipe symbols? What does `-->` mean? Does it mean the file is rewritten, or something else? What is `TCR`? What are the 5 files called? How do their names relate to `a.txt`, `b.txt` et al?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Records are delimited by linefeeds and the fields in each record by pipe symbols.. --> means , if it is a.txt file . I want a header like this, 'TCR1|A|B|C|D|E|F|# of records in first text file'. similarly for the other text files too

Comment: I asked you to clarify 5 things please.

Comment: Oops sorry again. a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt and e.txt are the 5 big text files. A specific name has been assigned to each text files such as "a.txt has TCR1" and "b.txt has TCR2" and "c.txt and TCR 3" and so on. Yes they should be rewritten

Comment: Use `wc -l < "$filename"` to get the number of records in the file.

Comment: Loop through all the files. Use `wc -l` to get the number of lines into a variable. Then write the header line with that variable followed by `cat "$filename"` to the new file.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks for the edit. I don't want to create a new file. The existing files should be rewritten with the header on top. All these files have been exported from SQL. So,the number of records are actual number of records of data in SQL not the number of text lines in the text file.

Comment: this getting to a shaggy-dog Q. Please edit your Q to show the smallest sample set of input data that describes the problem, the required output from that sample data and the your best attempt to solve the problem in code. If you have a solution for file `a.txt` won't that work for `b-e.txt`? While a bit general, Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably what you mean, though your question is very poorly posed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't crash if no text files present and allow upper/lowercase "txt/TXT"
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

# Declare "lines" to be numeric, rather than string
declare -i lines

for f in *.txt; do
   lines=$(wc -l < "$f")
   echo "$f|A|B|C|D|E|F|$lines"
   cat "$f"
done
```

---

I don't understand the `TCR` thing, but maybe this is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare "lines" to be numeric, rather than string
declare -i lines

for f in *.txt; do
   lines=$(wc -l < "$f")
   TCRthing="unknown"
   [ "$f" == "a.txt" ] && TCRthing="TCR1"
   [ "$f" == "b.txt" ] && TCRthing="TCR2"
   [ "$f" == "c.txt" ] && TCRthing="TCR3"
   [ "$f" == "d.txt" ] && TCRthing="TCR4"
   [ "$f" == "e.txt" ] && TCRthing="TCR5"
   echo "$TCRthing|A|B|C|D|E|F|$lines"
   cat "$f"
done
```

---

Note that there are simpler, more idiomatic ways of doing this, for example, you could just run:

```
more *.txt
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to get status as to which file you are viewing and where you have reached and how many lines each file is. You can also press <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to move to the next file and <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to move to the previous file. And <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to go back to top of current file and <kbd>G</kbd> to go to bottom of current file.

Comment: Actually your answer helped. Thanks a lot!!